# Proper expression for end credits

Tags: cinema

I'm putting words on the end(closing) credits of my frag movie, and what I want to put is who made the animation, who sang the song and who composed them.

I'm not sure if below expressions are correct for end credits.

- `Animated by` Company
- `Sung by` Singer
- `Composed by` Person

I guess the last two are okay, but I'm wondering whether I should say `animation by` not `animated by`.

Comment: Your  credits, your choice

Comment: There are millions of movies out there with credits, take a look at how they're written and use that as a model.